fs.readdir give no results and no errors
Here is my function (which should rename the newest file of a given directory, if the file has a type of extension) :
const fs = require('fs').promises; // Note the .promises
function renameLatestFile(directory, extension) {
    
    
    console.log("Start : " + directory);


    return fs.readdir(directory, { withFileTypes: true })
        .then(files => {
            console.log("après readdir", files.length, "files found");
            if (!files.length) {
                throw new Error("Directory is empty or does not exist");
            }
            return files;
        })
        .then(files => {  console.log("A"); Promise.all(    
            
            files.filter(file => !file.isDirectory() && path.extname(file.name) === extension)
                .map(file => 
                    fs.stat(path.join(directory, file.name))
                        .then(stats => ({
                            name: file.name,
                            time: stats.mtime.getTime()
                        }))
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error("Failed to get stats for file:", file.name, err);
                            throw err;
                        })
                ))
        })
        .then(fileDetails => {
            console.log("après sort");
            fileDetails.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);

            if (fileDetails.length === 0) {
                throw new Error('No files with the specified extension found in the directory.');
            }

            const latestFile = fileDetails[0].name;
            const newFileName = Date.now().toString() + path.extname(latestFile);
            const oldPath = path.join(directory, latestFile);
            const newPath = path.join(directory, newFileName);

            console.log("avant rename");
            return fs.rename(oldPath, newPath).then(() => {
                console.log("après rename");
                return newFileName;
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error during file operations:", err);
            throw err; // Ensure the error is thrown for external handling
        });

}

As you can see I put a console.log everywhere..
but when I call this function, except the first console.log("start") none of them is executed, even the one in the catch. The function do nothing, and no error message.
I'm lost (chatGPT don't know why too)
Any clue?
Thanks

In the second then you don't return anything, therefore you 1. fire off something that is not waited for 2. you don't get any value for the next .then() handler

in the second "then", the first instruction is a console.log("A"); I should see a A in the console if this second then was executed.
